# How do I compose these widgets to get this row to display correctly?

Tags: flutter

I am working on a form and trying to lay out the components on-screen. Each piece of data to be collected is represented by a left-aligned label above an empty, outlined form field. These are all inside a column, inside a singlechildscrollview, inside a safearea.

I have one pair of data points I'd like to put on a single row, such that the left item is a left-aligned label above a partial-width form field, and the right item is a right-aligned switch with a label to the left.

I can get all the components to appear on a single row, but I can't get the left-aligned label to work, I can't get the label/switch combo to vertically align to the center of the textfield, and I can't get the label/switch combo to be right-aligned. The image below is where I'm stuck; here's the code that got me there.

What am I missing here? I feel like it's something simple but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
                //* AMOUNT & DEPOSIT
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text('Amount'.hardcoded, style: labelStyle),
                          vgap(5),
                          TextFormField(
                            keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                                decimal: true),
                            autofocus: true,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 4, 0, 4),
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(),
                              ),
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.black38,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text('Deposit'.hardcoded, style: labelStyle),
                          hgap(5),
                          Switch.adaptive(
                            value: isDeposit,
                            onChanged: (value) =>
                                setState(() => isDeposit = value),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```

[image]

Comment: rather than using  Text('Amount'.hardcoded, style: labelStyle), remove that line and inside textformfield inside that decoration use  decoration: const InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Amount', ... use labelText propery of textform field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you trying to do?

[image: demo]

```
Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text('Amount',style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium,),
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: TextFormField(
                    keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                        decimal: true),
                    autofocus: true,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 4, 0, 4),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(),
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.black38,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                const SizedBox(width: 20,),

                Text('Deposit',style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium,),
                const SizedBox(width: 5,),
                Switch.adaptive(
                  value: true,
                  onChanged: (value){},
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
```